# Reflecting on a Type parameter

Tags: reflection, idris

I am trying to create a function

```
import Language.Reflection
foo : Type -> TT
```

I tried it by using the `reflect` tactic:

```
foo = proof
  {
    intro t
    reflect t
  }
```

but this reflects on the variable `t` itself:

```
*SOQuestion> foo
\t => P Bound (UN "t") (TType (UVar 41)) : Type -> TT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection in Idris is a purely syntactic, compile-time only feature. To predict how it will work, you need to know about how Idris converts your program to its core language. Importantly, you won't be able to get ahold of reflected terms at runtime and reconstruct them like you would with Lisp. Here's how your program is compiled:

1. Internally, Idris creates a hole that will expect something of type `Type -> TT`.
2. It runs the proof script for `foo` in this state. We start with no assumptions and a goal of type `Type -> TT`. That is, there's a term being constructed which looks like `?rhs : Type => TT . rhs`. The `?foo : ty => body` syntax shows that there's a hole called `foo` whose eventual value will be available inside of `body`.
3. The step `intro t` creates a function whose argument is `t : Type` - this means that we now have a term like `?foo_body : TT . \t : Type => foo_body`.
4. The `reflect t` step then fills the current hole by taking the term on its right-hand side and converting it to a `TT`. That term is in fact just a reference to the argument of the function, so you get the variable `t`. `reflect`, like all other proof script steps, only has access to the information that is available directly at compile time. Thus, the result of filling in `foo_body` with the reflection of the term `t` is `P Bound (UN "t") (TType (UVar (-1)))`.

If you could do what you are wanting here, it would have major consequences both for understanding Idris code and for running it efficiently.

The loss in understanding would come from the inability to use parametricity to reason about the behavior of functions based on their types. All functions would effectively become potentially ad-hoc polymorphic, because they could (say) run differently on lists of strings than on lists of ints.

The loss in performance would come from representing enough type information to do the reflection. After Idris code is compiled, there is no type information left in it (unlike in a system such as the JVM or .NET or a dynamically typed system such as Python, where types have a runtime representation that code can access). In Idris, types can be very large, because they can contain arbitrary programs - this means that far more information would have to be maintained, and computation occurring at the type level would also have to be preserved and repeated at runtime.

If you're wanting to reflect on the structure of a type for further proof automation at compile time, take a look at the `applyTactic` tactic. Its argument should be a function that takes a reflected context and goal and gives back a new reflected tactic script. An example can be seen [in the `Data.Vect` source](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/43127b17a765dbab2e7bcb6be2f6f2efc7a42386/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L36-L40).

So I suppose the summary is that Idris can't do what you want, and it probably never will be able to, but you might be able to make progress another way.